# Working with Firebase in development and production databases

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, nosql

I'm starting a new project using Firebase as my database to store the data of my application. Let's say, I finish my app and it's deployed in the app stores, so real users are using my app and they are entering new data to my Firebase database, what happens If I want to add a new functionality to my app, obviusly I cannot use the database that are using my real users, so I create a new Firebase project called myapp-dev, I import the data from my production database and I work in there, I added new data and new inserts/updates that will modify the structure of my production database, is there a way that I can combine the 2 databases dev into prod to not generate conflicts???

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase team recommends using two different projects to isolate different working environments.  It's not advised to combine them into a single project.